# Error when trying to update specific SQL Server table column based on the highest Id of the table row

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, sql-update

I am trying to update a specific column inside a SQL Server table where the Id of the row in which the column is, is the highest Id currently inside the table. The error message says that there is a syntax error near "ORDER" inside my query

I have done some research already on whether it is possible to use a SQL `UPDATE` statement followed by an `ORDER BY` statement, so that I update a specific column in the row with the highest Id in the table. I have found out that it is possible and what the syntax is, yet I still get an error when I follow the guidelines I have found and use the syntax.

My connection code that is linked to a button event:

```
SqlConnection newconnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["derpection"].ConnectionString);
string sql01 = "UPDATE Messages SET Besked = 'test' ORDER BY Id";

SqlCommand hmm01 = new SqlCommand(sql01, newconnection);

newconnection.Open();
hmm01.ExecuteNonQuery();
newconnection.Close();
```

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Messages] 
(
    [Id]       INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Besked]   VARCHAR(50)  NULL,
    [BrugerID] INT          NOT NULL,
    [Username] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Users] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([BrugerID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([Id])
);
```

I expect it to update the row with the highest Id, but the result is an error message. Even though the syntax should be right.

Comment: Your question explicitly specifies MySQL, but the code is not compatible with that database.  Very confusing.

Comment: kind of curious about where you found order by can be used on Update statement?

Comment: Hello, just double checked, you are right Gordon Linoff. It is just called a Sql Server Database on the list where i add it in Visual Studio. So i am sorry for my ignorance. I am a beginner at databases as you can probably tell. Here is the specific link Steve. https://dzone.com/articles/update-row-highest-id-mysql Found something similar somewhere else but now i cnanot find the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[ WITH <common_table_expression> [...n] ]  
UPDATE   
    [ TOP ( expression ) [ PERCENT ] ]   
    { { table_alias | <object> | rowset_function_limited   
         [ WITH ( <Table_Hint_Limited> [ ...n ] ) ]  
      }  
      | @table_variable      
    }  
    SET  
        { column_name = { expression | DEFAULT | NULL }  
          | { udt_column_name.{ { property_name = expression  
                                | field_name = expression }  
                                | method_name ( argument [ ,...n ] )  
                              }  
          }  
          | column_name { .WRITE ( expression , @Offset , @Length ) }  
          | @variable = expression  
          | @variable = column = expression  
          | column_name { += | -= | *= | /= | %= | &= | ^= | |= } expression  
          | @variable { += | -= | *= | /= | %= | &= | ^= | |= } expression  
          | @variable = column { += | -= | *= | /= | %= | &= | ^= | |= } expression  
        } [ ,...n ]   

    [ <OUTPUT Clause> ]  
    [ FROM{ <table_source> } [ ,...n ] ]   
    [ WHERE { <search_condition>   
            | { [ CURRENT OF   
                  { { [ GLOBAL ] cursor_name }   
                      | cursor_variable_name   
                  }   
                ]  
              }  
            }   
    ]   
    [ OPTION ( <query_hint> [ ,...n ] ) ]  
[ ; ]  

<object> ::=  
{   
    [ server_name . database_name . schema_name .   
    | database_name .[ schema_name ] .   
    | schema_name .  
    ]  
    table_or_view_name}
```

This is the full valid syntax tree for update statement in Sql Server and `Update .. Order By` is not one of them.

You can however use a sub query to do what you want

```
UPDATE Messages SET Besked = 'test'
WHERE Id IN (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Messages ORDER BY Id DESC)
```

Comment: Thanks alot Steve. The one with the sub query did the trick. I will read up on the IN statement and how to use sub queries to get a better understanding.